# How make a ticket booking app like BookMyShow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-shader, fragmenttransaction

I am building an app which has similar functionally like booking tickets in BookMyShow app.

In my application there are free seats and reserved seats which can be distinguished by color. Also if an user selects a seat that seat be highlighted(or changes color).

I have no idea how to go about it, please Point me in the right direction as I'm new to android.

Answer (score -1):

Well i am also very new to app development world. But i would suggest you a very simple and tricky approach.
You can build a responsive mobile website using javascript frameworks like angularjs,reactjs,ionic,sencha touch or touchstone js.
And render full website in a WEBVIEW using cordova or something.
As i said this approach is the simplest and may not fullfill your needs but is th trickiest one for app development.